# ImageButton getting bigger and bigger

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide, android-imagebutton

I use glide to load an image in an ImageButton view. Clicking on the button opens the camera and the picture taken goes on the Button. 
I'm facing a rather strange problem, at every picture taken, the image on the button become bigger..

Do you have an idea why ?

Some code might help :

```
// I use this to update the ImageButton
RequestManager glide = Glide.with(this);
glide.clear(mLeftTopImageButton);
glide.load(file.getAbsolutePath()).into(mLeftTopImageButton);
```

On the xml file :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <ImageButton
        android:background="?android:colorBackground"
        android:id="@+id/button1_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

edit:

Here is an exemple in image

[image]
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Bigger how? Height, width or both? Does `ImageView` gets bigger or just image?

Comment: Based on the image size, it will increase/decrease the ImageButton dimensions. So try to fix the dimensions of the ImageButton if you want to make look of images consistent.

Comment: The width should be fixed already by the `LinearLayout` weight right ?
I will add 2 screenshots showing the problem

Comment: Seems like it's because of different height of Images, see 2nd ss's Left top View and Right top View, First (left) has less height 2nd one has more height, Width also changes according to height and as you don't have the fixed height, this is happening. In short, try fixing the Height instead of Wrap Content.

Comment: Okay thanks it worked, but I still think it's strange that the height of pictures changes.. 
Thanks anyway (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @"Lalit Singh Fauzdar" said it was enough to fix the height in order to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Glad to see it.